# Equality of structures containing numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

It's well-known that `==` on numpy arrays returns an array rather than a bool, but this is very inconvenient at times.

```
>>> [np.zeros(4)] == [np.zeros(4)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

In my case, I have a huge structure of nested dicts, lists, etc, which occasionally contains numpy arrays. The fact that they can potentially contain numpy arrays means that `==` can't be used for comparisons since it will occasionally throw exceptions, so instead I need to traverse it manually. This is slow, verbose, and just overall annoying. Is there any better workaround?

Comment: how many layers of nesting do you have in the structures?

Comment: did you try `all((a == b).all() if isinstance(a, np.ndarray) else a==b for a, b in zip(A, B))` ?

Comment: The only shortcut to traversing the structure, manual or in builtin Python code, is to test for identical `id`.

Comment: Testing for identical IDs is not a solution. It's essentially a slower, bug-prone version of `is`, testing whether two objects are actually the same object. (It's bug-prone because it doesn't even correctly test whether the objects are the same object if the lifetimes don't overlap.)

Answer (score -1):

**np.array_equal** seems to do the trick:
From the doc:

```
>>> np.array_equal([1, 2], [1, 2])
True
>>> np.array_equal(np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]))
True
>>> np.array_equal([1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
False
>>> np.array_equal([1, 2], [1, 4])
False
>>> a = np.array([1, np.nan])
>>> np.array_equal(a, a)
False
>>> np.array_equal(a, a, equal_nan=True)
True
```

It seems to work well also with object with any level of nesting:

```
x = {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': True}}}}}}}}
y = {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': True}}}}}}}}
>>> np.array_equal(x, y)
True

z = {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': False}}}}}}}}
>>> np.array_equal(x, z)
False

u = {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
v = {'b': 1, 'a': 0}
>>> np.array_equal(u, v)
True
```

Comment: [This fails in a test where the nested data structures include actual NumPy arrays.](https://ideone.com/486yTZ)